# Fisher matrix for a discrete distribution

Tags: maximum-likelihood, inference, estimators, fisher-information

Let $\mathbf{X} = \{X_1, \ldots, X_n\}$ be a sample of i.i.d. variables following a discrete distribution with parameters $\mathbf{p}^T = (p_1, p_2, p_3)$. How can I find the Fisher information matrix for the MLE estimator $\mathbf{\hat{p}}$?

**My attempt so far:**

I can compute the MLE estimator $\mathbf{\hat{p}}^T = \left(\frac{n_1}{n}, \frac{n_2}{n}, \frac{n_3}{n}\right)$ by maximing the Lagrangian
$$\mathcal{L} = n_1 \log p_1 + n_2 \log p_2 + n_3 \log p _3 + \lambda (p_1 + p_2 + p_3 - 1).$$

I've also attempted to find the Fisher information matrix for $\mathbf{\hat{p}}$. In order to do so, I've expressed the log-likelihood in terms of the basis $(p_1, p_2)$:
$$l(p_1, p_2) = n_1 \log p_1 + n_2 \log p_2 + (n - n_1 - n_2) \log (1 - p_1 - p_2).$$

Computing derivatives with respect to $p_1$, $p_2$ and $1 - p_1 - p_2$ and taking the expectation yielded the matrix

$$\mathbf{I} = \frac{n}{1 - p_1 - p_2}
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1 - p_2}{p_1} & 1 & -1 \\    
1 & \frac{1 - p_1}{p_2} & -1 \\
-1 & -1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
.$$

The whole derivation is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlcwQ.jpg). However, its inverse does not equal anything close to the variance matrix that I'm expecting, namely
$$
\Sigma = \frac{1}{n}
\begin{pmatrix}
p_1(1-p_1) & -p_1p_2 & -p_1p_3 \\    
-p_1p_2 & p_2(1-p_2) & -p_2p_3 \\
-p_1p_3 & -p_2p_3 & p_3(1-p_3)
\end{pmatrix}
.$$

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:**

We can just focus on the two degrees of freedom that we have, which yields
$$
\mathbf{I} = \frac{n}{1 - p_1 - p_2}
    \begin{pmatrix}
     \frac{1 - p_2}{p_1} & 1 \\
     1 & \frac{1 - p_1}{p_2} \\
    \end{pmatrix}
.$$

Then, we get the expected asymptotic covariance matrix
$$
\mathbf{\Sigma} = \mathbf{I}^{-1} = \frac{1}{n}
    \begin{pmatrix}
     p_1(1-p_1) & -p_1p_2 \\
     -p_1p_2 & p_2(1-p_2) \\
    \end{pmatrix}
.$$

However, is there a way to find the covariance matrix for the whole vector $\mathbf{p}^T = (p_1, p_2, p_3)$?

Comment: In your first sentence are you talking about a *multinomial distribution*?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution

Comment: @Glen_b Yes, but the variables are numbered, so there is no need for the combinational factor.

Comment: You cant simply take the derivative w.r.t $1-p_1-p_2$ because it depends on $p_1$ and $p_2$. Treat this as a 2-parameter problem and you will get the expected result (i.e. invert the 2x2 part of $I$)

Comment: @J.Delaney Thank you! Yes, indeed, if we focus just on $p_1$ and $p_2$, then we get the expected result (see edits below). However, is there a way to express the asymptotic covariance matrix for the entire three dimensional parameter vector $\mathbf{p}^T = (p_1, p_2, p_3)$?

Comment: Yes, but that matrix will necessarily be singular (of rank no greater than $2$).  You were doing fine at the beginning until you dropped $p_3.$  Return there, keep $p_3,$ and do your calculations again.

Comment: @whuber Sorry, I'm not quite sure what you mean :( Where did I drop $p_3$?

Comment: It disappeared when you introduced $l$ following "I've also attempted..."  It never shows up again except where you state you would like to see it!

Comment: @whuber So I keep the likelihood as $l = n_1 \log p_1 + n_2 \log p_2 + n_3 \log p_3$? But then the Fisher matrix would be diagonal, wouldn't it?